# Split train and test data for image classification CNN

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

So i have binary classification problem for image, there are balanced dataset for class a and b.

I have 307 images for each class. i want to ask, when i split to train and test dataset, should the train and test also balanced for each class? or any method to split the dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit` which uses stratified random sampling, proportional random sampling, or quota random sampling. This will give a better distribution.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
# dummy dataset
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X, y)

print(sss)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

307 can be low for a CNN, you can also use data augmentation to increase your samples.

https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor

Comment: thank you for your insight will try it, also yeah it's pretty low dataset but i don't know which augmentation should i use, because the images is 2 channel (black and white) with size 32x32 cannot be blurred or distorted, what do you think about it?

Comment: Do you mean single channel gray or binary image? You should be able to apply any augmentation if it doesn't destroy major features. You can try augmenting with different effects like simple Gaussian Noise, contrast, salt & pepper initially.

Comment: oh yes single channel with grey, and one more, what is the ideal amount of data for this classification?

Comment: It depends on the model, the more the better always. For a simple CNN model, try augmenting to make around 1000 per class.

Comment: i think my model is simple with 2 convolutional layers, fyi my model goal is to classfy motion based on motion history image (MHI)

Comment: Yes, start with 1000 images per class, the problem with too much augmentation can result in a poor results. Also, you need to experiment to find the best set of hyperparameters including augmentation details.